# How to use pivot in a recursive stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot

I am separating a `varchar` according to `spaces` (I know the no. of spaces)

I am using a `stored procedure (Recursive)` to do so

```
Alter procedure [dbo].[1234]
   @name varchar(100),
   @count int 
AS 
BEGIN 

    if @count=1
    begin
        set @name=SUBSTRING(@name,CHARINDEX(' ',@name,1)+1,LEN(@name))
        select @name
    end
    if @count>1
    begin
        select SUBSTRING(@name,1,CHARINDEX(' ',@name,1)-1)
        set @count=@count-1
        set @name=SUBSTRING(@name,CHARINDEX(' ',@name,1)+1,LEN(@name))
        exec [dbo].[1234] @name,@count
    end
END
```

I execute the following SP on

```
exec [dbo].[1234] 'a b c d e f g h',8
```

And my result is 
[image]

but i want my result as

[image]

Comment: Wait I have a rotating screen in my room...

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Lucky you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Alter procedure [dbo].[1234]
   @name varchar(100)
as   
Select @name='Select' + ''''+Replace(@name,' ',''',''')+''''
EXEC( @name)

GO

[1234] 'A b c d e f'
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a920/1).

Comment: Wow, simple and ingenious!